# Change the Decimal Separator from

Tags: notepad++

how to change the decimal separator from (comma) to (dot).
Example:

```
,010',
```

to

```
.010',
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this replacement in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
,(\d{3})
```

**Replace:**

```
.\1
```

This will work fine so long as your numbers don't appear in a CSV list.  An instance where this solution would fail is the following case:

```
1000,1001,1002
```

which would be changed to

```
1000.1001.1002
```

which isn't what you intended.

Comment: this appear in a long string of sql (like ,'X',34,012,'ABC') and change only the comma in the number

Comment: Problem: it's impossible to know whether e.g. `34,123` means `34.123` (one number) or it means two numbers `34` and `123`.  It might be easier for you to change your source data rather than try to hack in Notepad++.

Comment: i have more then 30k lines to change and in some cases this happens 2 times. Even more then 4 digits before the comma don't have any char so "10000,56" must change to "1000.56"

Comment: Regex works well when you have a fixed structure to work with.  You should update your question with all edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if you have decimals like '123,123'
[image]

Comment: I think you intended to use `(\d+),(\d+)`

Comment: Could you write this image text out, Slava, As in the future the image file may no longer be accessible and that would completely nullify this answer.